# Pandas Boolean .any() .all()

Tags: python, pandas

I kept getting `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().` when trying boolean tests with pandas. Not understanding what it said, I decided to try to figure it out.

However, I am totally confused at this point.

Here I create a dataframe of two variables, with a single data point shared between them (3):

```
In [75]:

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()

df['x'] = [1,2,3]
df['y'] = [3,4,5]
```

Now I try all(is x less than y), which I translate to "are all the values of x less than y", and I get an answer that doesn't make sense.

```
In [79]:

if all(df['x'] < df['y']):
    print('True')
else:
    print('False')
True
```

Next I try any(is x less than y), which I translate to "is any value of x less than y", and I get another answer that doesn't make sense.

```
In [77]:

if any(df['x'] < df['y']):
    print('True')
else:
    print('False')
False
```

In short: what does any() and all() actually do?

Comment: I get true in both cases. Are you sure this is the example you are testing?

Comment: Take a look at just `df['x'] < df['y']`.  It does an elementwise comparison; i.e it is the Series `[df['x'][0] < df['y'][0], df['x'][1] < df['y'][1], etc]`.  Then `all(df['x'] < df['y'])` is True because all the elements in that Series are True.

Comment: I can't reproduce the bug you observe.  For me, `if any(df['x'] < df['y']): print('True')` does emit `True`.  You may be doing something strange in intermediate statements; try `print(df['x'],df['y'],df['x']<df['y'])` at "the moment of truth" and tell us what you see!

Comment: Wow that is crazy. I get True and False. I'm using py3 if that matters. Wow strange!

Comment: Can you post some example code that produces your original `'The truth value of a Series is ambiguous'` error? I think you're getting confused between the builtin `any()` and `all()` functions and the `a.any()`, `a.all()` methods of Numpy arrays/Python series.

Comment: Sorry are you including the last statement as part of your code because I get `True` and `True` for both your snippets but I notice that you are not displaying `Out [79]:` or `Out [77]:` so I'm wondering if you are either just including the output as part of your snippet for convenience or you are actually executing the statement `False` for example for your second snippet

Comment: By the way a more pythonic way of your if's would be to do something like `print any(df['x'] < df['y'])`.

Comment: Here the the code that produces the original error: if df['x'] < df['y']:
    print('True')
else:
    print('False')

Comment: FWIW the only case in which `all(x) == True` **and** `any(x) == False`, is when `x` has zero elements.

Answer (score 14):

Pandas suggests you to use Series methods `any()` and `all()`, not Python in-build functions.

I don't quite understand the source of the strange output you have (I get True in both cases in Python 2.7 and Pandas 0.17.0). But try the following, it should work. This uses `Series.any()` and `Series.all()` methods.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()

df['x'] = [1,2,3]
df['y'] = [3,4,5]

print (df['x'] < df['y']).all() # more pythonic way of
print (df['x'] < df['y']).any() # doing the same thing
```

This should print:

```
True
True
```

Comment: AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-318-991ef83ffb5f> in <module>
      5 
      6 #print (df['x'] < df['y']).all() # more pythonic way of
----> 7 print (df['x'] < df['y']).any() # doing the same thing

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'any'

Answer (score 0):

To compare two `pd.DataFrame` objects for both content and structure equality you can use:

```py
import pandas as pd

def are_df_equal(df: pd.DataFrame, df2: pd.DataFrame) -> bool:
    return df.equals(df2) and (df.all() == df2.all()).all()
```