# Multiple conditional average python

Tags: python, pandas

What I'm trying to do is a multiple conditional average. It means that I have a list of x variables (of the same length) and I'd like to compute the average of one variable conditioned to the value/range of the others.

The file is:
[image: It is a sample file]

The code I tried is:

```
wb=pd.ExcelFile('file.xlsx')
wb.sheet_names
df=wb.parse('Sheet1')
df[:]
Var1=df['Col1_Name']
Var2=df['Col2_Name']
Var3=df['Col3_Name']
Var4=df['Col4_Name']
Var5=df['Col5_Name']
Var6=df['Col6_Name']

if (Var1 == 0).any() and (Var2 == 0).any() and (Var3 < 0.8).any() and (Var6 == 0).any():
    print sum(Var4)/len(Var4)
```

It seems to be ok, but, if I change the conditions, the result is always the same. Moreover I tried to calculate the same on Excel as double check and the result is indeed different..
Could you help me? Thank you :)

Comment: It probably didnt print anything, because the condition was not met. Check the condition.

Comment: A sample of your input file could help

Comment: that's not the way `.all()` is used based on the documentation. Do some more reading... Take a look at that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27791651/pandas-boolean-any-all

Comment: Thank you Nikolas. I've just tried with a simplified condition: if(Var1.all==0):
    print sum(Var4)/len(Var4) but it is the same..

Comment: all(iterable):
Return True if all elements of the iterable are true (or if the iterable is empty).
`Var1.all()==0`, (with `()`) do not check if every one in the col is not null, it would check if there is one cell in the col var1 that is not iterable

Comment: Thank you guys .. I'll read more on .all and I'll let you know

Comment: `var.all` is not even Python.

Comment: Thank you .. it seems to work with: if (Var1 == 0).any() and (Var2 == 0).any() and (Var3 >= 0).any() and (Var3 < 1).any() and (Var6 == 0).any():
    print sum(Var4)/len(Var4)

Comment: Sorry guys, do you have some suggestion?

Answer (score 3):

What you have written seems all sorts of wrong.  I believe what you want is:

```
(Var1 == 0).all() and (Var2 == 0) and (Var3 >= 0).all() and (Var3 < 1).all() and (Var6 == 0).all()
```