# Create a new column with IF-THEN in grouped pandas df

Tags: pandas

I'm applying a simple function to a grouped pandas df. Below is what I'm trying. Even if I try to modify the function to carry one step, I keep getting the same error. Any direction will be super helpful.

```
def udf_pd(df_group):
if (df_group['A'] - df_group['B']) > 1:
    df_group['D'] = 'Condition-1'
elif df_group.A == df_group.C:
    df_group['D'] = 'Condition-2'
else:
    df_group['D'] = 'Condition-3'

return df_group

final_df = df.groupby(['id1','id2']).apply(udf_pd)
final_df = final_df.reset_index()


ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, 
a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: It's unclear where the `group` even matters. `(df_group['A'] - df_group['B']) > 1` returns a Series. Do you need to check if anything within the group satisfies that condition? or perhaps every row needs to satisfy that?

Comment: The group does matter for the way I'd like to manipulate and represent the data. So, that condition check is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that in *groupby.apply* the function is applied to **the whole group**.
On the other hand, each *if* condition must boil down to a **single** value
(not to any *Series* of *True/False* values).

So each comparison of 2 columns in this function must be supplemented with
e.g. *all()* or *any()*, like in the example below:

```
def udf_pd(df_group):
    if (df_group.A - df_group.B > 1).all():
        df_group['D'] = 'Condition-1'
    elif (df_group.A == df_group.C).all():
        df_group['D'] = 'Condition-2'
    else:
        df_group['D'] = 'Condition-3'
    return df_group
```

Of course, the function can return the whole group, e.g. "extended"
by a new column and in such a case a **single** value of the new column
is **broadcast**, so each row in the current group receives this value.

I created a test DataFrame:

```
   id1  id2  A  B  C
0    1    1  5  3  0
1    1    1  7  5  4
2    1    2  3  4  3
3    1    2  4  5  4
4    2    1  2  4  3
5    2    1  4  5  4
```

In this example:

- In the first group (*id1 == 1*, *id2 == 1*), in all rows, *A - B > 1*,
  so *Condition-1* is *True*.
- In the second group (*id1 == 1*, *id2 == 2*), the above condition is
  **not** met, but in all rows, *A == C*, so *Condition-2* is *True*.
- In the last group (*id1 == 2*, *id2 == 1*), neither of the above
  conditions is met, so *Condition-3* is *True*.

Hence the result of `df.groupby(['id1','id2']).apply(udf_pd)` is:

```
   id1  id2  A  B  C            D
0    1    1  5  3  0  Condition-1
1    1    1  7  5  4  Condition-1
2    1    2  3  4  3  Condition-2
3    1    2  4  5  4  Condition-2
4    2    1  2  4  3  Condition-3
5    2    1  4  5  4  Condition-3
```

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered this error before and my understanding that pandas isn't sure which value it's supposed to run the conditional against. You're going to probably want to use `.any()` or `.all()`. Consider these examples

```py
>>> a = pd.Series([0,0,3])
>>> b = pd.Series([1,1,1])
>>> a - b
0   -1
1   -1
2    2
dtype: int64

>>> (a - b) >= 1
0    False
1    False
2     True
dtype: bool
```

you can see that (a-b) >= 1 truthiness is kinda ambigious, the first elements in the vector is false while the others are true.

Using `.any()` or `.all()` will evaluate the entire series.

```py
>>> ((a - b) >= 1).any()
True
>>> ((a - b) >= 1).all()
False
```

`.any()` checks to see if well any of the elements in the series are True. While `.all()` checks to see if **all** of the elements are True. Which in this example they're not.

you can also check out this post for more information: [Pandas Boolean .any() .all()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27791651/pandas-boolean-any-all)