# Failing to use pandas .all() properly

Tags: python, pandas

Apparently I am failing to understand how .all() works.

My example data:

```
df=pd.DataFrame([[-1,-1,-1],[1,1,1],[-1e-8,-1e-8,1e-8]],columns=['col0','col1','col2'])
df


col0    col1    col2
0   -1.000000e+00   -1.000000e+00   -1.000000e+00
1   1.000000e+00    1.000000e+00    1.000000e+00
2   -1.000000e-08   -1.000000e-08   -1.000000e-08
```

Now, I would like to select only the rows where all values are positive (index 1 in this example), so I tried to build a mask:

```
mask=[i for i in df.index if df.loc[i,:].all()>0]
```

But the conditional in the list comprehension:

```
df.loc[0,:].all()>0
True
```

returns True, even though all of the values in row 0 are negative. In fact, I get True no matter what part of df I use:

```
df.all(axis=1)>0
True
df.all()>0
True
```

I'm so baffled I must be missing something simple.

Comment: You are using it in a wrong order. Use `df.gt(0).all(1)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Boolean .any() .all()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27791651/pandas-boolean-any-all)

Comment: For the second part of the question you are not comparing the entries of df, use ```(df > 0).all(1)``` and this will give you the correct result. Also as stated by @Chris you have to correct the order to ```df.gt(0).all(1)```

Comment: Thanks Chris and Sachin Kumar. It is clear now I was "reading" it wrong in my head. Makes perfect sense. mikksu that answer is informative and indirectly answers my question. I'm fine with this question being deleted... if that is acceptable.